# Rails dependent collection_select fields in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm working on a rails app but cannot find how to handle dependent drop down lists.
I have 3 models:
- Category which has several groups
- Group which has several members
- Member

When a category is selected, I'd like the groups within this category to populate the second drop down list (and same thing between group and member).

I have the following form (obviously this is not working how I'd like as I take all the items for the particular model)...

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.collection_select(:category, Category.find(:all), :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'Category'}) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.collection_select(:group, Group.find(:all), :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'Group'}) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.collection_select(:member, Member.find(:all), :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'Member'}) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to make those fields dependent ? I found several topics regarding this on the web but could not really find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of doing it is AJAX call.
In the starting just populate category drop-down. And on change of category make an ajax call and populate groups. And do same for the members on groups drop-down change.

Try something like this:

```
$("#category']").click(function(){
  var url = '/get_drop_down_options?category_id=' + $(this).val()
  $("#group").removeOption(/./)
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#group').addOption(data, false);
  });
});
```

In your controller:

```
def get_drop_down_options
  val = params[:category_id]
  #Use val to find records
  options = YourModel.collect{|x| "'#{x.id}' : '#{x.label}'"}    
  render :text => "{#{options.join(",")}}" 
end
```

Now you dont need partial.

Comment: Yes. jQuery will be most suitable for your requirement

Comment: hmmm... I still have a strange thing when I use JQuery. $.getJSON will retrieve something like  {'1' : 'first','2' : 'second'} but this JSON guy is flagged as invalid JSON... would you have any idea ?

Comment: Yes, I understood, it should be {"1" : "first","2" : "second"}, with double cote instead of single one.

Comment: Definitely the right approach.  I was not able to get .click to work in Chrome, but .change works fine, and has the added benefit of only making the AJAX/JSON call when the selection is changed.

Comment: Does one need some sort of plugin for this? When I try this solution, I get a TypeError that "addOption" is not a method for that object.

Comment: You need only jQuery for this solution.

Comment: [There is no such jQuery function called `.addOption()`](http://jquery.com/?s=addOption).

Comment: great idea you save my day

Answer (score 0):

I would have a different Id for each field, and use some jquery animation and ajax magic:
When a field is clicked I would do an ajax call to retrieve all the records of the subgroup, once i got them, make appear that div with a slide down animation, or similar.