# Rails: dependent collection_select fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two fields in my Rails application: **language** and **word**. The words table is quite large, and as such I'd like to have the selection filtered by the choice of language. Below is code from the **edit** view and you can see how I have hard-coded in the language in the second **collection_select**.

```
.field
  = f.label :language_id
  = f.collection_select :language_id, Language.find(:all,:conditions => ["supported = 't'"]),:id,:language_code, include_blank: false, :title => 'Language'
.field
  = f.label :word
  = f.collection_select :word_id, Word.find(:all,:conditions => ["language_id = 2"]), :id, :word, include_blank: false, :title => 'Word'
```

A similar question was posted on SO, but the solution provided was to use AJAX. I would prefer to reduce the database load by adding a criteria after the user can selected the language. 
[Rails dependent collection_select fields in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311284/rails-dependent-collection-select-fields-in-form)

Is it possible for the Rails code to assess the chosen value of **:language_id** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the object containing the fields is Article :

```
= f.select :word_id, Word.where(:language_id => @article.language_id).map {|w| [w.name, w.id]}
```