# update options of select when other select change

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to update the options of my second select box when my firt select box change,
but i dont know how to do this.

I want to select all Stores from Client

my .html.erb

```
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :client_id %><br>
        <%= f.select :client_id, Client.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]} %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :store_id %><br>
        <%= f.select :store_id, Store.where(:client_id => :client_id).collect {|l| [store.name, store.id]} %>
    </div>
```

I'm thinking of using JQuery to do this. But how do I update the select box? 
Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: watch this video - http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311284/rails-dependent-collection-select-fields-in-form