# Dropdown depending on another collection_select rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, collection-select

Guys that is my code thing is I want to select a parent subject and upon selection I need to use that selected subject to list the topics within it in the parent field how can i do that?

```
    <label>Parent Subject</label>
    <div class="field">
      <%= collection_select :topic, :subject_id, Subject.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
    <label>Parent Topic</label>
    <div class="field">
      <%= collection_select :topic, :parent_id, ?????, :id, :name %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this help? [Rails dependent collection_select fields in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311284/rails-dependent-collection-select-fields-in-form)

If not, I am about to build something and might be happy to share it if it isn't to ugly!