# Rails, Jquery: Dependent Dropdowns error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement 3 dependent dropdowns using `collection_select` and Jquery. I have a model called `Categories` which has 3 fields: `main`, `sub`, and `sub sub`. I have another model `product` which belongs to a category. A category `has_many` products.

When creating a product, I need to select the category it falls into. To do that, first the user chooses the `main`, and from there the list of `sub` fields is filtered to only have the ones which correspond to `category_ids` where the `main` field is the `main` selected. The same filtering then happens for `sub_sub`.

I have started by just trying to implement the `sub` filtering. Here is my code.

`products_controller.rb`:

```
  def get_dropdown_options
    val = params[:main]
    Category.where(main: val).uniq.pluck(:sub)
  end
```

The relevant part of `form`:

```
<%= f.fields_for @category do |builder| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= builder.label 'Category' %><br>
    <%= builder.collection_select :main, Category.get_uniq_fields(:main), "to_s", "to_s",  {:include_blank => 'Main'}, remote: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= builder.label 'Sub Category' %><br>
    <%= builder.collection_select :sub, [], "to_s", "to_s", {:include_blank => 'Sub'}, remote: true%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= builder.label 'Sub Sub Category' %><br>
    <%= builder.collection_select :sub_sub, [], :sub_sub, "to_s", {:include_blank => 'Sub Sub'} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#product_category_main").change(function(){
    var url = '/products/new/get_dropdown_options?main=' + $(this).val();
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('select#product_category_sub').addOption(data, false);
    });
  });
});
```

When I select a `main`, I keep getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` coming from the `$('select#product_category_sub').addOption(data, false);` line in the javascript.

I'm new to javascript with Rails and am therefore really struggling to figure out what's going wrong. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Edit 0: the JS I used comes from this answer: [Rails dependent collection_select fields in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311284/rails-dependent-collection-select-fields-in-form).

**Edit 1:** How do I use the result of the `get_dropdown_options` method in the controller as the options for the second collection_select?

**Edit 2:** I have changed the method to this:

```
def get_dropdown_options
   val = params[:main]
   options = Category.where(main: val).collect { |x| "'#{x.id}' : '#{x.sub}'"}
   render text: "{#{options.join(",")}}"
end
```

to basically be outputting a json like object, and the javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#product_category_main").change(function(){
    var url = '/products/new/get_dropdown_options?main=' + $(this).val();
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $.each(url, function(key, value) {   
         $('#selectproduct_category_sub')
        .append($('<option>', { value : key })
        .text(value)); 
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But still struggling to understand how to add the options outputted by the get_dropdown_options method.

Can anyone help with that please?

Comment: Where does `addOption` come from?  That's probably the issue.  It's not defined anywhere.  There is no such jQuery function.

Comment: @Sparky But how do I use the options generated from the get_dropdown_options method as the options in that second collection_select? I used this Jquery code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311284/rails-dependent-collection-select-fields-in-form to help.

Comment: [There is no such jQuery function called `.addOption()`](http://jquery.com/?s=addOption) unless you create it yourself.  Scour the jQuery docs and Google for yourself.  Meanwhile, I've down-voted that other answer for referencing it.  See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311284/rails-dependent-collection-select-fields-in-form#comment15851454_5311320).

Comment: @Sparky thank you. I'm just struggling to understand how to populate the second collection_select with the output of the get_dropdown_options method.

Comment: You haven't shown the view for `get_dropdown_options`, but what you want is to render a JSON dict with your options. If `sub` is the user-visible text, you'll probably also want to include some kind of id to use as the option's value -- typically, you'd use the `id` field from the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps here that are required to make this all work right.

First, you want to have your controller render JSON for the options. Something like:

```
def get_dropdown_options
   val = params[:main]
   render json: Category.where(main: val)
end
```

Next, you have to make your AJAX request when the user changes the select value and then process the response (which should actually be a list of categories, where each category has been rendered as a plain old Javascript object).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#product_category_main").change(function(){
    var url = '/products/new/get_dropdown_options?main=' + $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, category) {   
         $('#selectproduct_category_sub')
        .append($('<option>', { value : category.id })
        .text(category.sub)); 
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The call to getJSON makes the request to the controller method in your server, receives the response and converts it from its textual JSON representation to a javascript object. It then calls your function, passing that object as `data`. Your function iterates over the object (which is an array of objects), extracting the relevant fields from each and building an option.